# Авто обнаружение AWS RDS инстансов в Zabbix

Tags: zabbix, amazon

Известно что Zabbix может обнаруживать новые хосты базируясь на многочисленных проверках. Нужно обнаруживать только Amazon RDS сервера и автоматически добавлять найденные в Zabbix как новый отдельный хост. Есть много решений для интеграции RDS и Z., но все они базируются на Low-Level Discovery правилах, которые создают только новые метрики на одном заданном хосте, поэтому не подходят.

Нужно создавать для каждого AWS RDS отдельный новый хост, и назначать на него шаблоны. Можно было бы фильтровать по TCP сервису на порту 3306, для обнаружения MySQL, но в инфраструктуре могут быть ещё и не RDS сервера с MySQL на них.

Поэтому дополнительный фильтр должен быть применен - обратное преобразование IP адреса найденного хоста в DNS имя, - будет содержать строку "rds.amazonaws.com", как можно задать такой фильтр в правиле сетевого обнаружения или в действия привязанных к этому правилу?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решилось всё-таки Low-level discovery правилами, которые могут создавать "Host prototype" а уже на созданный хост мы назначем шаблоны. Таким образом не создаются хосты которые имеют запущенный MySQL и не являются RDS инстансами, потому что discovery правилу находит только RDS.